# Sorting an array related to another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays, `x` and `y`, where y is the value of the tens of every element in `x`. Now, I want to sort `y`. But, the order of `y` will be different of `x`'s. So, I can't tell after sorting which element in `y` was related to, for instance, `x[0]`.

I want a "double sorting" maybe.

Comment: What language are we talking about? Are there any performance constraints?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`Array.Sort` has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3.aspx) that accepts **two** arrays; one for the keys, and one for the items. The items of **both** are sorted according to the `keys` array:

```
int[] keys = { 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
string[] items = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno" };
Array.Sort(keys, items);
foreach (int key in keys) {
    Console.WriteLine(key); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
foreach (string item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item); // abc, jkl, ghi, def, mno
}
```

So in your case, it sounds like you want:

```
Array.Sort(y,x); // or Sort(x,y); - it isn't  100% clear
```

Comment: Will it not work, if my both keys array and value array are integers ? I just tried it and it doesn't sort either of the array.

Comment: @Auro I'd need to see code to comment; details matter

Comment: Thanks Marc. I needed to sort two list. and I used the ToArray() extension. That was the mistake. Upon converting it to a new array( i mean the keys and vaues) it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

How about?

```
var selectedArr = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
var unorderArr = new int[] { 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 };
var orderedArr = unorderArr.OrderBy(o => selectedArr.IndexOf(o));
```

Comment: This has poor time complexity and will fail on duplicates.

Comment: @user2864740, yes I agree, but it works at least

Answer (score 2):

If we have two arrays of complex objects and want to sort them according to one of the two arrays then we can use the next approach:

```
// We want to sort "people" array by "Name" and
// accordingly to it reorder "countries" array.
Person[] people = new Person[]
{
    new Person {Name = "Fill"},
    new Person {Name = "Will"},
    new Person {Name = "Bill"},
};

Country[] countries = new Country[]
{
    new Country {Name = "Canada"},
    new Country {Name = "UK"},
    new Country {Name = "USA"}
};

// Here we sort "people" array, but together with each "Person"
// in sorted array we store its "index" in unsorted array. Then we
// will use this "index" to reorder items in "countries" array.
var sorted = people
    .Select((person, index) => new {person, index})
    .OrderBy(x => x.person.Name)
    .ToArray();

// Here "people" array is sorted by "Name", and
// "contries" array is reordered accordingly to it.
people = sorted.Select(x => x.person).ToArray();
countries = sorted.Select(x => countries[x.index]).ToArray();
```

---

Another approach is to use overload of the method [`Array.Sort with IComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort__2___0_____1___System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___0__). At first we should implement `IComparer`:

```
private class PeopleComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
```

And then we can sort two our arrays:

```
Array.Sort(people, countries, new PeopleComparer());
```

---

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8X7vO6) that demonstrates these two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If y is always the tens value of x, y probably shouldn't exist - you should probably just calculate it's value directly off of x when needed.

In general, sorting parallel arrays is only possible (without hand rolling a sort algorithm) when the sort algorithm takes a custom "swap" function, which you can implement in terms of swapping elements in both arrays simultaneously. std::sort in C++ and qsort in C don't allow this.

Also in the general case, consider a single array where the element is a pair of items, rather than a parallel array for each item. This makes using "standard" algorithms easier.