# Sorting many TValue arrays with one TKey array

Tags: c#, .net, performance, algorithm, sorting

I have an outer array of N inner arrays of size M. I want to sort each inner array according to another array `K` exactly in the same way as a built-in `Array.Sort<TKey, TValue> Method (TKey[], TValue[], IComparer<TKey>)` [.NET method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8kwfbye%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964234/sorting-an-array-related-to-another-array).

The method modifies the Key array after sorting, so I can use it to sort only single inner array. To sort many arrays, I copy the `Key` array to another `KeyBuffer` array for each inner array, reusing the KeyBuffer on each sorting step and avoiding allocation and GC. Is that the most efficient way if the typical N is 10K-100K and M < 1000? Given the low size of M the copying and sorting should be done in CPU cache, - which is the fastest that I can get?

My concern is that by doing so, I am sorting the buffer and discarding the results (N-1) times, which is a kind of waste. Also I am doing actual sorting N times, but after the first sorting I already know a map of old indexes to new indexes and I could somehow reuse that mapping for other (N-1) steps.

How would you avoid unnecessary sorting and apply known mapping from the first step to other steps?

Here is the code how I do it now. The question is if it is possible to do it more efficiently.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MultiSorting {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var N = 10;
            var M = 5;
            var outer = new List<string[]>(N);

            for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                string[] inner = { "a" + i, "d" + i, "c" + i, "b" + i, "e" + i };
                outer.Add(inner);
            }

            int[] keys = { 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 };

            var keysBuffer = new int[M];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                Array.Copy(keys, keysBuffer, M);
                // doing sort N times, but we know the map 
                // old_index -> new_index from the first sorting
                // plus we sort keysBuffer N times but use the result only one time
                Array.Sort(keysBuffer, outer[i]); 
            }
            keys = keysBuffer;

            foreach (var key in keys) {
                Console.Write(key + " "); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                foreach (var item in outer[i]) {
                    Console.Write(item + " "); // a{i}, b{i}, c{i}, d{i}, e{i}
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any code to post instead of describing it?

Comment: @L.B added code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just played with this and implemented mapping reuse directly in a `for` loop. I didn't expect that a simple loop instead of native built-in methods could speed up things, probably because I had underestimated algorithmic costs of sorting vs costs of array looping and I used to relax when a profiler said the job was mostly done inside .NET methods...

`Naive` is the code from the question, `ReuseMap` is what is described in words in the question, `Linq` is from the answer by @L.B. `...InPlace` modifies input, `...Copy` doesn't.

Results with N = 2000, M = 500, 10 runs, in milliseconds:

- NaiveInPlace: 1005
- ReuseMapInPlace: 129 (Log2(500) = 9.0, speed-up = 7.8x)
- NaiveCopy: 1181
- ReuseMapCopy: 304
- LinqCopy: 3284

The entire test is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace MultiSorting {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {

            const int n = 2;
            const int m = 10;

            var keys = GenerateKeys(m);
            foreach (var key in keys) {
                Console.Write(key + " "); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            var keysBuffer = new int[keys.Length];
            Array.Copy(keys, keysBuffer, keys.Length);
            Array.Sort(keysBuffer);
            foreach (var key in keysBuffer) {
                Console.Write(key + " "); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            // warm up, check that output is the same
            List<string[]> outer = MultiSortNaiveInPlace(keys, GenerateOuter(n, m));
            PrintResults(outer);
            outer = MultiSortNaiveCopy(keys, GenerateOuter(n, m));
            PrintResults(outer);
            outer = MultiSortReuseMapInPlace(keys, GenerateOuter(n, m));
            PrintResults(outer);
            outer = MultiSortReuseMapCopy(keys, GenerateOuter(n, m));
            PrintResults(outer);
            outer = MultiSortLinqCopy(keys, GenerateOuter(n, m));
            PrintResults(outer);

            // tests
            keys = GenerateKeys(500);
            NaiveInPlace(2000, 500, keys);
            ReuseMapInPlace(2000, 500, keys);
            NaiveCopy(2000, 500, keys);
            ReuseMapCopy(2000, 500, keys);
            LinqCopy(2000, 500, keys);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void NaiveInPlace(int n, int m, int[] keys) {
            const int rounds = 10;
            var source = new List<List<string[]>>(rounds);
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source.Add(GenerateOuter(n, m));
            }
            GC.Collect();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source[i] = MultiSortNaiveInPlace(keys, source[i]);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("NaiveInPlace: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        }

        private static void ReuseMapInPlace(int n, int m, int[] keys) {
            const int rounds = 10;
            var source = new List<List<string[]>>(rounds);
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source.Add(GenerateOuter(n, m));
            }
            GC.Collect();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source[i] = MultiSortReuseMapInPlace(keys, source[i]);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("ReuseMapInPlace: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        }

        private static void NaiveCopy(int n, int m, int[] keys) {
            const int rounds = 10;
            var source = new List<List<string[]>>(rounds);
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source.Add(GenerateOuter(n, m));
            }
            GC.Collect();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source[i] = MultiSortNaiveCopy(keys, source[i]);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("NaiveCopy: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        }

        private static void ReuseMapCopy(int n, int m, int[] keys) {
            const int rounds = 10;
            var source = new List<List<string[]>>(rounds);
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source.Add(GenerateOuter(n, m));
            }
            GC.Collect();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source[i] = MultiSortReuseMapCopy(keys, source[i]);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("ReuseMapCopy: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        }

        private static void LinqCopy(int n, int m, int[] keys) {
            const int rounds = 10;
            var source = new List<List<string[]>>(rounds);
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source.Add(GenerateOuter(n, m));
            }
            GC.Collect();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
                source[i] = MultiSortLinqCopy(keys, source[i]);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("LinqCopy: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        }

        private static void PrintResults(List<string[]> outer) {

            for (var i = 0; i < outer.Count; i++) {
                foreach (var item in outer[i]) {
                    Console.Write(item + " "); // a{i}, b{i}, c{i}, d{i}, e{i}
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

        }

        private static int[] GenerateKeys(int m) {
            var keys = new int[m];
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { keys[i] = i; }
            var rnd = new Random();
            keys = keys.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
            return keys;
        }

        private static List<string[]> GenerateOuter(int n, int m) {
            var outer = new List<string[]>(n);

            for (var o = 0; o < n; o++) {
                var inner = new string[m];
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { inner[i] = "R" + o + "C" + i; }
                outer.Add(inner);
            }
            return outer;
        }

        private static List<string[]> MultiSortNaiveInPlace(int[] keys, List<string[]> outer) {
            var keysBuffer = new int[keys.Length];
            foreach (var inner in outer) {
                Array.Copy(keys, keysBuffer, keys.Length);
                // doing sort N times, but we know the map 
                // old_index -> new_index from the first sorting
                // plus we sort keysBuffer N times but use the result only one time
                Array.Sort(keysBuffer, inner);
            }
            return outer;
        }

        private static List<string[]> MultiSortNaiveCopy(int[] keys, List<string[]> outer) {
            var result = new List<string[]>(outer.Count);
            var keysBuffer = new int[keys.Length];

            for (var n = 0; n < outer.Count(); n++) {
                var inner = outer[n];
                var newInner = new string[keys.Length];
                Array.Copy(keys, keysBuffer, keys.Length);
                Array.Copy(inner, newInner, keys.Length);
                // doing sort N times, but we know the map 
                // old_index -> new_index from the first sorting
                // plus we sort keysBuffer N times but use the result only one time
                Array.Sort(keysBuffer, newInner);
                result.Add(newInner);
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static List<string[]> MultiSortReuseMapInPlace(int[] keys, List<string[]> outer) {
            var itemsBuffer = new string[keys.Length];
            var keysBuffer = new int[keys.Length];
            Array.Copy(keys, keysBuffer, keysBuffer.Length);
            var map = new int[keysBuffer.Length];
            for (int m = 0; m < keysBuffer.Length; m++) {
                map[m] = m;
            }
            Array.Sort(keysBuffer, map);

            for (var n = 0; n < outer.Count(); n++) {
                var inner = outer[n];
                for (int m = 0; m < map.Length; m++) {
                    itemsBuffer[m] = inner[map[m]];
                }
                Array.Copy(itemsBuffer, outer[n], inner.Length);
            }
            return outer;
        }

        private static List<string[]> MultiSortReuseMapCopy(int[] keys, List<string[]> outer) {
            var keysBuffer = new int[keys.Length];
            Array.Copy(keys, keysBuffer, keysBuffer.Length);
            var map = new int[keysBuffer.Length];
            for (int m = 0; m < keysBuffer.Length; m++) {
                map[m] = m;
            }
            Array.Sort(keysBuffer, map);
            var result = new List<string[]>(outer.Count);
            for (var n = 0; n < outer.Count(); n++) {
                var inner = outer[n];
                var newInner = new string[keys.Length];
                for (int m = 0; m < map.Length; m++) {
                    newInner[m] = inner[map[m]];
                }
                result.Add(newInner);
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static List<string[]> MultiSortLinqCopy(int[] keys, List<string[]> outer) {
            var result = outer.Select(arr => arr.Select((item, inx) => new { item, key = keys[inx] })
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.key)
                                    .Select(x => x.item)
                                    .ToArray()) // allocating
                  .ToList(); // allocating
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```