# Descending sorting of a list of object based on a count from a different class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, lambda

I'm stuck on this problem where I need to do descending sort based on other list. l_lstNames need to update by age descending.

```
public class Test
{
    public String Name;
    public Int32 Age;
}

List<String> l_lstNames = new List<String> { "A1", "A3", "A2", "A4", "A0" };

List<Test> l_lstStudents = new List<Test> 
{ 
    new Test { Age = 33, Name = "A0" }, 
    new Test { Age = 10, Name = "A1" }, 
    new Test { Age = 50, Name = "A2" }, 
    new Test { Age = 8,  Name = "A3" }, 
    new Test { Age = 25, Name = "A4" }, 
};

// Output
List<String> l_lstNames = new List<String> { "A2", "A0", "A4", "A1", "A3" };
```

Found few sames samples but not matching what I'm looking for. Thank you for help.

Comment: +1 for concise example and desired output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array related to another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964234/sorting-an-array-related-to-another-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `Dictionary<string, int>` with `Name` to `Age` mapping and use it within order method:

```
var dict = students.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Age);

var ordered = source.OrderByDescending(x => dict[x.Name]).ToList();
```

or you can just order `students` collection and then select `Name` only:

```
var ordered = students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age)
                      .Select(x => x.Name)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect! Infact my student list is in dict and it just took your one line code to get the solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the names in order descending:

```
var sorted = l_lstStudents           // From the list of students
    .OrderByDescending(l => l.Age)   // with the oldest student first
    .Select(s => s.Name)             // give me just the names
    .ToList();                       // in a list!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
List<String> l_lstNames1 = (from student in l_lstStudents
                          where l_lstNames.Any(a => student.Name == a)
                          orderby student.Age descending
                          select student.Name ).ToList();
```

OR

```
List<String> l_lstNames2 = l_lstStudents.OrderByDescending(a => a.Age)
                                .Where(a => l_lstNames.Any(b => b == a.Name))
                                .Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
```