# C# Sorting a string array alphabetically using elements in another array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

For an assignment I have to sort a bunch of employees alphabetically by their department.

For example:

```
David
Hunter
1
Admin

John
Smith
11
Sales

Jane
Appleby
5
Accounts

Michelle
Page
12
Sales

Peta
Jones
13
Admin
```

should become

```
Jane
Appleby
5
Accounts

David
Hunter
1
Admin

Peta
Jones
13
Admin

John
Smith
11
Sales

Michelle
Page
12
Sales
```

I want to use a bubblesort for this but I have no idea how to get it to sort by anything other than the first name. This is what I have so far:

```
string[] people = record.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string person in people)
{
    string[] details = person.Split('\n');
    firstName = details[0];
    lastName = details[1];
    empID = details[2];
    department = details[3];
}         

for (int i = 1; i < people.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < people.Length - i; j++)
    {                   
        //people.department doesn't work
        if (people.department[j].CompareTo(people.department[j + 1]) > 0)
        {
            temp = people[j];
            people[j] = people[j + 1];
            people[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do with a bubblesort like this, and access the department of an employee? Should I consider other ways that might be better/ more simple?

Comment: Why would you ever "want" to use bubblesort?

Comment: Do  you have a `List<People>`?

Comment: Sort is not a problem here, your input is. You're parsing your input, but not storing it anywhere. Create a `Person` class, get a `List<Person>` and add all your data into it within first `foreach`. Sort that list instead of `string[]` you're trying to sort now.

Comment: Question looked like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964234/sorting-an-array-related-to-another-array based on title, but turns out title is not related to post much.

Comment: You can do this very easily just in a few lines using LINQ, but of course that may not give you the mark for the assignment. However, the goal of the assignment is for you to learn, but you will learn nothing if we give you the answer. You will get the mark and learn nothing. If I were you, I'd go back to the textbook and lectures, study the `bubblesort` carefully, try to apply it, and come back here to ask questions, but only after truly try and fail to find the answers. This is how people learn.

Comment: @rmn36 He doesn't "want", his teacher "wants" :-). Have you noticed that the question started with "For an assignment"? :-)