# Object to comma separated string

Tags: c#, string

is there a way to make a comma separated from an object. Note its object not List of object

Ex:

```
public class EmployeeLogReportListViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
    public string Employer { get; set; }
}
```

With the following values

```
Date = "2018/02/03"
EmployeeID = 111
Time = 11:53 AM
Sort = 1
Employer = EMP
```

this should result into

```
2018/02/03,111,11:53 AM,1 EMP
```

What is the best way to make this. possible single line of code cause i dont want to use string builder and append all of it.

Comment: How will you use it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Backs will put it on a list of string

Comment: please see the edited text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Challenge accepted

```
var o = new EmployeeLogReportListViewModel();
var text = string.Join
(
    ",",
    typeof(EmployeeLogReportListViewModel)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Select
        (
            prop => prop.GetValue(o).ToString()
        )
);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Technically that is one line.

If you want the properties sorted alphabetically, you could use this:

```
var o = new EmployeeLogReportListViewModel();
var text = string.Join
(
    ",",
    typeof(EmployeeLogReportListViewModel)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .OrderBy( prop => prop.Name )
        .Select
        (
            prop => prop.GetValue(o).ToString()
        )
);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: This answer suits best in terms of scalability.When you add properties to the class then it works without changing anything. Currently its throwing a null reference exception because Employer is null. For using this we have to make sure that none of the properties of the class are null. Else we get null reference.

Comment: i love this approach but how would you modify it if you wanted them in a specific order?

Comment: @MikeMurphy Add an [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) clause before `Select`

Comment: This code was exactly what I needed. I will add it to my lib and give John Wu credit. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

I think you are looking for Overridden `.ToString()` method. you have to modify the class like this:

```
public class EmployeeLogReportListViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", this.Date, this.EmployeeID, this.Time, this.Sort, this.Employer);
    }
}
```

[Usage Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4M07OG):

```
EmployeeLogReportListViewModel objVm = new EmployeeLogReportListViewModel();
// Assign values for the properties
objVm.ToString(); // This will give you the expected output
```

Where the `String.Format()` can be replaced with string interpolation like the following

```
public override string ToString()
{
  // return $"Date:{this.Date},EmployeeID:{this.EmployeeID},Time:{this.Time},Sort:{this.Sort},Employer:{this.Employer}";
  // To get the mentioned OP. ie., 2018/02/03,111,11:53 AM,1 EMP
  return $"{this.Date.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")},{this.EmployeeID},{this.Time.ToString("hh:mm tt")},{this.Sort},{this.Employer}";
}
```

Comment: String interpolation can also be used in C# 6.

Comment: @SecretCoder  What if tomorrow you want to add a new property to the class? You have to change the override ToString() method. You do not work on it and new developer comes and simply forgets to override ToString() . It can cause errors/bugs in what not many places. Just a thought.

Comment: what i like about this example is it lets you control the order of the values in the resulting delimited string

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late to reply, but I can imagine you want to do that in order to have some kind of csv output style

a nice and generic way to do it is to create a extension method that transform any Enumerable into a csv string.

so borrowing @John Wu's solution, we come up with something like

```
public static class EnumerableToCsvExtension
{
    public static string ToCSVString<TContent>(this IEnumerable<TContent> enumerable, char propertySeparator = ',', bool includeHeader = true)
    {
        var properties = typeof(TContent).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        var header = string.Join(propertySeparator, properties.Select(p => p.Name));
        var rows = enumerable.ToList().ConvertAll(item => string.Join(propertySeparator, properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item) ?? string.Empty )));

        var csvArray = includeHeader ? rows.Prepend(header) : rows;

        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, csvArray);
    }
}
```

then you use it like

```
var list = new List<EmployeeLogReportListViewModel> { new EmployeeLogReportListViewModel(), new EmployeeLogReportListViewModel() };
list.ToCSVString();
list.ToCSVString(propertySeparator: '|', includeHeader: false);
```

Comment: is there a way to specify the order of the values in the resulting delimited string?

Comment: @MikeMurphy It can be easily done by add a extra argument like params string[] order, then sorting the *properties* array. For that take a look on how to sort a list in c# and use your imagination :) 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964234/sorting-an-array-related-to-another-array

Comment: Now, if your question is about Ordering by name, you can just use OrderBy or OrderByDescending

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
public class bKashAccountInfo
{
    public string bKashNumber { get; set; }
    public string bKashAccountType { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format($"bKash Number-{bKashNumber}, Account Type - {bKashAccountType}");
    }
}
```