# Get the generic of a method in a parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to reduce my code with generics.

I created a struct:

```
struct helperType<T> where T : IComparable<T> 
{
    public Vertex<TVertex> vertexValue;
    public T value;

    public helperType(Vertex<TVertex> vertex, T givenValue) {
        vertexValue = vertex;
        value = givenValue;
    }

}
```

`TVertex` is a class but not really relevant in my question.

I then created two array of this helperType:

````
helperType<bool>[] boolArr = new helperType<bool>[_nVertices];
helperType<int>[] distArr = new helperType<int>[_nVertices];```
````

I am now wondering if I could create a generic method that would get the right array regarding the type I give on call:

```
void ChangeArray<T>(helperType<T>[] arr, Vertex<TVertex> vertex, bool value)
{

    ...
}
```

This line generate an error as I guess the compiler don't get a type for my parameter.

```
void PrintArr<T>(helperType<T>[] arr) {} t
```

this give me an error on the T fro helperType:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
> or method 'Graph<TVertex, TEdges>.helperType'. There is no boxing
> conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to
> 'System.IComparable'. [GraphLibrary]csharp(CS0314)

Comment: how are `T` and `TVertex` related? I suppose `TVertex` should actually be `T`.

Comment: T and TVertex are not related. TVertex is its own class and works well. My problem is to connext the T from PrintArray<T> to the parameter helperType<T>[]. I want the second T to be equal to the first one, but I do not know how to do this

Comment: What is the actual intent? Do you want to associate each vertex with some arbitrary data? Can `TVertex` really be any arbitrary type, say a 'banana' or a 'person'?

Comment: TVertex is a generic for my Vertices proprieties. In this case it does not matter. 
My idea was to associate my vertex to a bool or an int as you guessed. Then I could use this array to perform some algorithm like Dijkstra

Answer (score 1):

The generic type parameter `T` has a constraint in its original class defination.

```
where T : IComparable<T>
```

So all the other generic type parameters must have the same constraint.

```
void ChangeArray<T>(helperType<T>[] arr, Vertex<TVertex> vertex, bool value)
    where T : IComparable<T>

void PrintArr<T>(helperType<T>[] arr) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Comment: Oh god, I did not see that! I removed it and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to manage the data in an structure-of-array (SoA) manner rather than array of structure (AoS).

```
public class MyHelper<TVertex, T> : IComparable<T> {
    public TVertex[] Vertices {get; init;}
    public T[] Data{get; init;}
}
```

This allows the same array of vertices to be used for multiple things at once, while using indices to associate each vertex to a corresponding data value. This way of storing data also tend to improve data locality, and that can help for some use cases.

If you want to sort values there [ways to sort both arrays together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964234/sorting-an-array-related-to-another-array).

This approach can absolutely be used for a closed set storage for djikstra. But you should probably not use it for the open set since it will be costly to keep it sorted. The typical structure for the open set is a [MinHeap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), since that has both efficient insertion of values and removal of smallest value.

My generic implementation of djikstra has a signature like this. Granted, it uses double rather than a generic type for the cost, but I have not found this to be a problem in practice. My implementations of the closed set either uses a pair of arrays or a dictionary:

```
public static (T FoundNode, double TotalCost) Search<T>(
  IEnumerable<T> from, 
  IEnumerable<T> to, 
  IGraph<T> graph, 
  IClosedStorage<T> closedStorage ) 
where T : IEquatable<T> {...}

public interface IClosedStorage<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        bool IsClosed(T node, out double dist);
        void Close(T node, double dist, T parent);
        T GetParent(T node);
    }
    public interface IGraph<in T> where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<(T Neightbor, double Cost)> GetNeighbors(T node);
    }
```

I hope it might serve as point of comparison at least.

Comment: Thank you, my actual solution is quite inefficient. I will try to refactor using your ideas.